# Jquery-Popbox closing when clicking datepicker inside

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Jquery-Popbox](http://gristmill.github.io/jquery-popbox/index.html) plugin for using as a date selection dropdown

It works fine until I add a Bootstrap Datepicker to it, and then when I click a date it closes the popbox for me. Does anyone know how I can keep it open when I click a date?

I have a live demo [on my site](https://www.drivingsuccess.co.nz/portal/stackoverflow/popbox-issue.html)

(I tried using `jquery-popbox` tag but I don't have enough rep to create it)

Comment: When you click anywhere outside of the popbox, the popbox hides. Datepicker generates the HTML outside the popbox hence when clicked popbox closes. I didn't find any option in popbox plugin to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the [following code](https://github.com/gristmill/jquery-popbox/blob/master/popbox.js#L41) as I have a close button anyway

```
$(document).bind('click', function(event){
  if(!$(event.target).closest(settings['selector']).length){
    methods.close();
  }
});
```